# Same algorithm gave very different metrics on similar datasets

Tags: random-forest

I am fairly new to ML and still in the learning phase.

I used Random Forest ( hypertuned the parameters) for a binary classification problem on one dataset ( dataset A). I got a F1 score of 0.78. I then got a second dataset(dataset B).It was very similar to dataset(A).By similar I mean same variables and the distribution of classes in the target variable.I again built and trained a different random forest algorithm for dataset B. I expected the f1 score to be around 0.78 , but the f1 score for dataset B was 0.50.

I don't understand why there is such a stark difference in the f1 scores for the 2 datasets.Both datasets ( A& B) are very similar to each other and I trained separate models on both of them.

Any inputs on how to approach this issue?Thanks!

Comment: Similar data isn't necessarily the same. Different data makes for a different model.

Comment: Without all the data, I doubt we can say much. Having the same variables and class distribution doesn't really mean the data are similar - why couldn't the relationships be very different?

Comment: yea thats what I realized. Similar doesn't always mean same.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do is check the baseline accuracy of the datasets you're working with by looking at the averages of your dependent variable in each dataset. It might be that the baseline accuracy for Dataset A is higher than Dataset B. It's also possible that despite having the same variables and similar distributions of those variables, the relationships between the variables in each dataset are not similar for whatever reason, like non-random sampling between the datasets, for example.

One more thing you could try is test other models on the datasets. A quick thing you could do is run a logit on each dataset and see if this stark performance difference exists in other models too, which would provide more evidence that it is a data issue and not a model definition issue.

Comment: thanks that makes sense.Also could you please elaborate of baseline accuracy for a certain dataset or point me towards some resources? By logit, do you mean logistic regression?Also if I find that its a dataset issue, is it possible to narrow down to what the issue is?

Comment: Baseline accuracy is essentially how accurate you would be with a very simple classification system. If, for example, your dependent variable is 60% 1s and 40% 0s, then you could achieve 60% accuracy by just predicting 1 for every observation, so we could say 60% is the baseline accuracy your model needs to beat. Here's an article on baselines. https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-get-baseline-results-and-why-they-matter/

Yeah logit is logistic regression. 

Possibly! I would guess the issue is that in Dataset B the explanatory variables don't correlate with your dependent variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the resource.Having a baseline accuracy makes so much sense

Comment: No worries, and don't forget to upvote or mark as answered if I've helped you figure out your issue! Good luck on future data endeavors.